# Magento 2 - Extend custom validation / add own validation rule

Tags: magento2, validation, custom-validation

In Magento 1, I used the below javascript code inside of a template to add my own validation rule:

```
// Add new validation class for the name. Also supports names with two hypen in the name e.g. Hans-Maier-Friedrich.
// Also supports umlauts and some special chars like é or á
Validation.add('validate-name','Please only use (A-Z a-z àèéáäÄüÜöÖ) in this field.', function(v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ]+-?[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ]+-?[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ]+$/.test(v);
});
```

How does it work in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below code, please replace validation rule  and error message

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'jquery/validate', 'mage/translate', 'mage/mage'
    ], function($){
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-name', function (value) {
                return /^0(6|7)[0-9]{8}$/.test(value); // your validation rule here
            }, $.mage.__('Your error message.'));

    });
</script>
```